# Complex lookahead/not-greedy regex

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string:

(it is all on a single line)

```
<IMG SRC="/include/images/moredetails.png" WIDTH="8" HEIGHT="7" ONMOUSEOVER="return createPopup('<b>[scan_name@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedName# --><br><b>[organization@user:home]:</b><br><!-- #EscapedOrganizationPath# --><br><b>[total@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedTotal# --><br><b>[high@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedHigh# --><br><b>[medium@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedMedium# --><br><b>[low@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedLow# --><br><b>[date_last_scanned@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedDate# -->');" ONMOUSEOUT="return nd(1000);"><!-- #Name# --></TD>
```

And the second string:

```
<IMG SRC="/include/images/moredetails.png" WIDTH="8" HEIGHT="7" ONMOUSEOVER="return createPopup('<b>[scan_name@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedName# --><br><b>조직/부서 경로:</b><br><!-- #EscapedOrganizationPath# --><br><b>[total@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedTotal# --><br><b>[high@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedHigh# --><br><b>[medium@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedMedium# --><br><b>[low@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedLow# --><br><b>[date_last_scanned@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedDate# -->');" ONMOUSEOUT="return nd(1000);"><!-- #Name# --></TD>
```

I want from the first string to find all the [..] place holders and find in the second string their Korean translation.

I wrote code that does this:

```
while($stringA =~ /(.*?)(\[[^\]]+?\])(.*?)/g) {
 my $prefix = $1;
 my $tag = $2;
 my $suffix = $3;
```

And then calls a regex on the `$prefix` and `$suffix`:

```
if ($stringB =~ /\Q$prefix\E(.*)\Q$suffix\E/g) {
```

*NOTE* The below copied examples don't escape `"`, I just did that to make it clearer

Problems:

A. `$prefix` and `$suffix` don't contain everything before and after that placeholder, because I am using non-greedy. Example:

```
$prefix = "<IMG SRC="/include/images/moredetails.png" WIDTH="8" HEIGHT="7" ONMOUSEOVER="return createPopup('<b>"
$tag = "[scan_name@user:home]"
$suffix = ""
```

B. If I don't use greedy `(.*)(\[[^\]]+?\])(.*)` I capture everything "correctly", but only the last tag gets caught. Example:

```
$prefix = "<IMG SRC="/include/images/moredetails.png" WIDTH="8" HEIGHT="7" ONMOUSEOVER="return createPopup('<b>[scan_name@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedName# --><br><b>[organization@user:home]:</b><br><!-- #EscapedOrganizationPath# --><br><b>[total@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedTotal# --><br><b>[high@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedHigh# --><br><b>[medium@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedMedium# --><br><b>[low@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedLow# --><br><b>"
$tag = "[date_last_scanned@user:home]"
$suffix = ":</b> <!-- #EscapedDate# -->');" ONMOUSEOUT="return nd(1000);"><!-- #Name# --></TD>"
```

**What I want**

I want to capture all the tags, and able to compare it to the translated string and return something like:

```
'[state@user:home] = '상태'
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It seems to me that you can use [`([^>]+):`](http://regex101.com/r/aY3hA0) to get all the matches you need for the comparison. Does that work for you?

Comment: Given I have no other way to contact you, please actually [read](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3715751) reviews before approving them.  Robo approving helps no one.

Comment: Yes, sorry that one missed me :{

Comment: @Daedalus - sorry, I missed it, don't know how

Comment: Thank you; just try and take it more slow in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
my $strA = q~<IMG SRC="/include/images/moredetails.png" WIDTH="8" HEIGHT="7" ONMOUSEOVER="return createPopup('<b>[scan_name@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedName# --><br><b>[organization@user:home]:</b><br><!-- #EscapedOrganizationPath# --><br><b>[total@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedTotal# --><br><b>[high@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedHigh# --><br><b>[medium@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedMedium# --><br><b>[low@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedLow# --><br><b>[date_last_scanned@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedDate# -->');" ONMOUSEOUT="return nd(1000);"><!-- #Name# --></TD>~;
my $strB = q~<IMG SRC="/include/images/moredetails.png" WIDTH="8" HEIGHT="7" ONMOUSEOVER="return createPopup('<b>[scan_name@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedName# --><br><b>조직/부서 경로:</b><br><!-- #EscapedOrganizationPath# --><br><b>[total@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedTotal# --><br><b>[high@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedHigh# --><br><b>[medium@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedMedium# --><br><b>[low@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedLow# --><br><b>[date_last_scanned@user:home]:</b> <!-- #EscapedDate# -->');" ONMOUSEOUT="return nd(1000);"><!-- #Name# --></TD>~;

while($strA =~ /(.*?)\[([^\]]+?)\](.)/g) {
    my $prefix = $1;
    my $tag = $2;
    my $suffix = $3;
    print "prefix=$prefix\ntag=$tag\nsuffix=$suffix\n";
    print "found it $1\n\n" if ($strB =~ /\Q$prefix\E\[?([^\[\]]+)\]?\Q$suffix\E/g);
}
```

If you want a longer suffix to avoid overlap, you can use this:

```
while($strA =~ /(.*?)\[([^\]]+?)\]([^[]*))/g) {
```

**Output:**

```
prefix=<IMG SRC="/include/images/moredetails.png" WIDTH="8" HEIGHT="7" ONMOUSEOVER="return createPopup('<b>
tag=scan_name@user:home
suffix=:
found it scan_name@user:home

prefix=</b> <!-- #EscapedName# --><br><b>
tag=organization@user:home
suffix=:
found it 조직/부서 경로

prefix=</b><br><!-- #EscapedOrganizationPath# --><br><b>
tag=total@user:home
suffix=:
found it total@user:home

prefix=</b> <!-- #EscapedTotal# --><br><b>
tag=high@user:home
suffix=:
found it high@user:home

prefix=</b> <!-- #EscapedHigh# --><br><b>
tag=medium@user:home
suffix=:
found it medium@user:home

prefix=</b> <!-- #EscapedMedium# --><br><b>
tag=low@user:home
suffix=:
found it low@user:home

prefix=</b> <!-- #EscapedLow# --><br><b>
tag=date_last_scanned@user:home
suffix=:
found it date_last_scanned@user:home
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like prefix and suffix to be a bit longer otherwise I risk overlaps, the prefix seems decent, can I make the suffix longer?

Comment: BTW: stringB will not have any placeholders [tag@pri:sec] it will have the words in most cases, so looking for [, and ] is wrong

Comment: @nrathaus:I've made them optional, remove them if they never occur.

Comment: @nrathaus: You can change the sufix to `[^[]`